# Understanding interferences between python importing policy and pytest mocking

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-mock

I am having some troubles in understanding how to properly mock a function using `pytest-mock` module.

I will report a minimal reproducible example:

file: `src/mini_handler.py`

```
import tempfile

from src.mini_pdf_handler import mini_pdf_handler


def mini_handler():
    tmp_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
    mini_pdf_handler()
    return tmp_file.name
```

file: `src/mini_pdf_handler.py`

```
import tempfile


def mini_pdf_handler():
    tmp_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
    return tmp_file.name
```

file: `tests/test_handler.py`

```
def test_mini_handler(mocker):
    mock_tempfile = mocker.MagicMock()
    mock_tempfile.return_value.name = 'outputs/output.pdf'

    mocker.patch("src.mini_handler.tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile", side_effect=mock_tempfile)

    mini_handler()
```

The problem is that the mock works, but it is mocking even the `NamedTemporaryFile` in the `mini_pdf_handler` module, when it should mock it only in the `mini_handler`. I have the feeling the problem might be in the import policy that python have, since once a module is imported, it won't import it again. At the same time, I feel that the problem might be some silly oversight. Can someone help me?

Comment: Your MRI would be more illustrative if those were prints instead of returns. You're not displaying any output at all, so anyone running it has no way of knowing what values are being generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you're patching "too deep".

Each module in `src/` has a reference to the `tempfile` module. You could mock `src.mini_handler.tempfile` and it would not impact `mini_pdf_handler`, but you're dereferencing `src.mini_handler.tempfile` by mocking `...tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile`, and in both modules this refers to the same thing.

You can fix it like this:

```
from src.mini_handler import mini_handler

def test_mini_handler(mocker):
    mock_tempfile = mocker.MagicMock()
    mock_tempfile.return_value.name = 'outputs/output.pdf'

    res = mocker.patch('src.mini_handler.tempfile')
    res.NamedTemporaryFile = mock_tempfile
    mini_handler()
```

Here we are replacing `src.mini_handler.tempfile` with a mock object. This doesn't impact the reference to `tempfile` in `src.mini_pdf_handler`. We then configure the `NamedTemporaryFile` attribute of our mock object.

---

In response to your comment:

Imagine we have the following dictionaries:

```
>>> tempfile = {'foo':'bar'}
>>> mini_handler = {'tempfile': tempfile}
>>> mini_pdf_handler = {'tempfile': tempfile}
```

If I modify `mini_handler['tempfile']['foo']...

```
>>> mini_handler['tempfile']['foo'] = 'qux'
```

...then that change is visible in both `mini_handler['tempfile']` and `mini_pdf_handler['tempfile']`, because both of these names refer to the same thing:

```
>>> mini_handler['tempfile']['foo']
'qux'
>>> mini_pdf_handler['tempfile']['foo']
'qux'
```

On the other hand, if I replace `mini_handler['tempfile']` with a different dictionary:

```
>>> mini_handler['tempfile'] = {'something': 'else'}
```

This is no longer the case:

```
>>> mini_handler['tempfile']
{'something': 'else'}
>>> mini_pdf_handler['tempfile']
{'foo': 'qux'}
```

The situation with modules and mocking in your test is exactly analagous to this example. Does that help?

Comment: Amazing, that works like a charm. Can you please explain a little better the dereferencing part? Or maybe pointing me to some docs somewhere? Thank you very much

Comment: I've updated my answer in response to your comment. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: That is perfectly clear now. Thank you!